# zsh: command not found: pub

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, zsh, aqueduct

I'm getting this error message when try to install aqueduct on macOS Catalina with this command.

```
pub global activate aqueduct
```

I managed to install it by putting flutter in front of it but now I cannot run aqueduct. I tried

```
aqueduct --version
```

I get an error again

> zsh: command not found: aqueduct

Here is my .zshrc file (I've added last second line to try to fix it)

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/peter/development/tools/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

I don't know what else to do...

Comment: did you get the same error on `bash` ?

Comment: @HugoS No I get `The default interactive shell is now zsh. To update your account to use zsh, please run 'chsh -s /bin/zsh'.`

Comment: @HugoS should I ran that command?

Comment: even with bash I get the error `bash: aqueduct: command not found`

Comment: Have you checked if there's a binary file `aqueduct` in folders "$PATH:/Users/peter/development/tools/flutter/bin" or "$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin", and that it's permissions are `rwx` ?

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk there seems to be no files `aqueduct` in "$PATH:/Users/peter/development/tools/flutter/bin" and there is no folder ".pub-cache" in my home directory

Comment: Have you installed Dart: https://dart.dev/get-dart ? This is required before setting up aqueduct

Comment: like `brew install dart` and other steps

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk I thought dart is installed together with flutter.... ok.. I'm doing it and let you know

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk that worked... can you put it as an answer so I can mark it as answered

Comment: @delmin : Did you check your PATH? Not by looking into your .zshrc, but by doing a echo $PATH just before running the command.

Comment: @user1934428 No i did not... but to be honest i think it only needed to install brew.. everything is working now. I had to reinstall xcode after that but i managed that as well after an hour of waiting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't know what is `aqueduct`, but this is a common way to solve such issues:

1. When you see `$ zsh: command not found: aqueduct`,

run `$ which aqueduct` - it shouldn't work.

If it works, then the shell **does** know about a binary named `aqueduct`.

2. Find out in which folder `aquedict` is located, and add the path to it in `export PATH=...`, like in you did in `.zshrc` file.
3. If you found aquedict binary, and it still fails to work, try adding it permissions to execute:

`chmod +rwx aquedict`

4. If you didn't found aquedict binary, read the docs again. :)

In your case it's https://aqueduct.io/docs/getting_started/ ,

and the first step is to install Dart: https://dart.dev/get-dart

Answer (score 25):

Edit zshrc file using vim on terminal

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

edit data on zshrc after pressing "i" on keyboard.
Export flutter location, aqueduct location and dart sdk location.

**NOTE, to change the **your_path** to your flutter directory. i.e where flutter is installed.**

```
export PATH="$PATH":"your_path/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"your_path/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"your_path/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
```

After editing press "esc" key and type `:wq` for saving
Check working of aqueduct using

```
aqueduct --version
```

or

```
aqueduct serve
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have flutter installed, try `flutter pub global activate aqueduct`

Answer (score 6):

I got this error `zsh: command not found: pub`

quick answer if you already have flutter installed

run

```
flutter pub get
```

because [You can either download the Dart SDK directly (as described below) or download the Flutter SDK, which (as of Flutter 1.21) includes the full Dart SDK.](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started#2-install-dart)

In my case I wanted to install dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` in my dart project, but got `zsh: command not found: pub`.

**What is `pub`**

[The `pub` tool has commands for managing packages and for deploying packages and command-line apps.](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd)